# Prestashop 1.7 Context::getContext() not working in AdminController

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-helper-classes

I have created custom admin controller in my custom module but i am not able to use `Context::getContext()` in my admin controller.

When i try to use that i am getting below error.

**Attempted to call an undefined method named "getContext" of class "PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\Shop\Context".
Did you mean to call e.g. "getContextListShopID", "getContextListShopIDUsingCustomerSharingSettings", "getContextShopGroup" or "getContextShopID"?**

I have already added this line at the top of my file  **use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\Shop\Context;**
but still facing same issue.

If anyone have any idea why `Context::getContext()` doesn't work I would like to hear it.

Thanks

Comment: Try using

PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\LegacyContext;

Comment: Post your codes plzzz

Comment: @user3256843 I've tried to use this as well  PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\LegacyContext; but still getting same issue. Please refer these two screenshot. 
https://prnt.sc/lgKJUzDnc8Jm
https://prnt.sc/ujGnc9QXIK8A

Comment: You could really do with improving the question. Add code even if it's just the class declaration and a snippet of the context (pardon the pun) that contains the call. I assume you're creating a symphony admin controller and not a legacy one, for example? What do you need to get the context for?

Answer (score 0):

Just put a `\` in front:

`\Context::getContext()`